# Why will this not return the element that i am clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p id="demo">Demo Element</p>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('#demo').click(() => {
          console.log(this)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the #demo paragraph, `this` returns the window object. Why does this happen and how can I not access the #demo paragraph using this method.

Answer (score 2):

Because you created the function using the arrow syntax:

```
()=>{

}
```

If you will create the function like this, it will work:

```
$('#demo').click(function() {
      console.log(this)
})
```

---

## More info

When using the arrow syntax for creating a function, this `this` element, stays as the same context of the same place you define it.

> An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: Thank you, I never knew this. I thought that the normal `function(){}` notation and the `() => {}` were the same thing just cleaner.

Comment: By the way, if you do `()=>{ console.log(arguments) }` you will get the arguments of the parent function.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you're using ECMAscript syntax. Arrow function syntax bind the data within the function to itself, whereas the regular function syntax does not.